CMake: find_package(protobuf) / protobuf-generate with only protoc available
I would like to use the protobuf_generate_python CMake function (see here) to generate some python files from my .protos.
I only have the downloaded protoc-binary and the includes available (no protobuf installation in the build system and also no complete protobuf compile from scratch, as it increases the build time drastically).
protoc is of course enough to compile the .protos, however the necessary find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED) fails in CMake as protobuf is not available.
Is there a way to use the handy protobuf_generate_python with only protoc and includes being available?

I don't understand your question but, if you have protoc, you can compile protos to Python e.g. protoc --proto_path=${PROTO_PATH} --python_out=${PWD} ${PROTO_PATH}/${PROTO}

You could copy cmake/protobuf-generate.cmake module to your project, include it, and use its protobuf_generate function. (The function protobuf_generate_python is just a wrapper for protobuf_generate: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/cmake/protobuf-module.cmake.in#L37)

@DazWilkin yes, of course I can, but using the existing cmake function is more handy.

@Tsyvarev hmm, that's an idea, but I was more hoping for a solution where I can set some cmake variables to make cmake not complain and just do the protobuf generate

Do you mean that you want to set some variables and call find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)? While it is possible, I don't find good an approach which sets variables to the non-existent libraries.

Yes, that was my idea. Still use the find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED) and pretend the non-existent libraries to be there, which is fine as they are not used during protobuf_generate
